# React - How to mock useFormContext (react-hook-form)

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using useFormContext  in one the child component.
this is the code for it:

```
const { register } = useFormContext<CustomerProfileFormData>();
```

How can I Mock useFormContext so that I can test child component.
this is the test

```
it('should render properly', () => {
    render(<AddressDetails isEdit={false} />);
    expect(screen.getByTestId('address-details')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'register' of '(0 , _reactHookForm.useFormContext)(...)' as it is null.Jest.

which makes sense since I did not mock useFormContext . How can I Mock it? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

You can either mock the context methods as indicated in other responses, or you can provide your component with an actual FormContext by creating an ad hoc wrapper component inside your test like this:

```
it('should do something', () => {
  const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const formMethods = useForm<CustomerProfileFormData>();

    return (
      <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
        {props.children}
      </FormProvider>
    );
  };

  render(
    <Wrapper>
      <AddressDetails />
    </Wrapper>
  );

  // your assertions here ... 
})
```

If you want to verify that your components behaves correctly upon form values, you could e.g. override the `getValues` method with preconfigured data.

```
const mockedGetValues = (key: string) => {
   // return test data for form key
}

return (
  <FormProvider {...formMethods} getValues={mockedGetValues}>
    {props.children}
  </FormProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

To make the `useFormContext` method work inside tests, RHF recommend wrapping it with `<FormProvider>` ([Github-How to Test FormProvider / useFormContext](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/3815)).

Wrap your component with `<FormProvider>` and provide the required methods like this:

```
render(
  <FormProvider {...({ setValue: () => jest.fn() } as any)}>
    <AddressDetails isEdit={false} />
  </FormProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

To mock react-hook-form v7 you can do as follow

```
jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-hook-form'),
  useFormContext: () => ({
    handleSubmit: () => jest.fn(),
    control: {
      register: jest.fn(),
      unregister: jest.fn(),
      getFieldState: jest.fn(),
      _names: {
        array: new Set('test'),
        mount: new Set('test'),
        unMount: new Set('test'),
        watch: new Set('test'),
        focus: 'test',
        watchAll: false,
      },
      _subjects: {
        watch: jest.fn(),
        array: jest.fn(),
        state: jest.fn(),
      },
      _getWatch: jest.fn(),
      _formValues: ['test'],
      _defaultValues: ['test'],
    },
    getValues: () => {
      return [];
    },
    setValue: () => jest.fn(),
    formState: () => jest.fn(),
    watch: () => jest.fn(),
  }),
  Controller: () => [],
  useSubscribe: () => ({
    r: { current: { subject: { subscribe: () => jest.fn() } } },
  }),
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works for me:

```js
jest.mock( "react-hook-form", () => ( {
  ...jest.requireActual( "react-hook-form" ),
  useFormContext: () => ( {
    handleSubmit: () => jest.fn(),
    getValues: () => jest.fn(),
  } ),
} ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was by signaling to `jest.fn()` when the function was called, this way it preserves the original flow and also serves to change and see how many times it was called and with what parameters it was called.

```
const spySetValue = jest.fn();
const spyReset = jest.fn();
const spySetFocus = jest.fn();

type Fn<T extends VoidFn> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>;
const createPreservedMock =
  <O extends Fn<O>>(original: O, mock: O) =>
  (...args: Parameters<O>) => {
    original(...args);
    return mock(...args);
  };

jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => {
  const module = jest.requireActual('react-hook-form');
  return {
    ...module,
    useForm() {
      const useFormOriginal = module.useForm();
      const useForm = {
        setValue: useFormOriginal.setValue,
        reset: useFormOriginal.reset,
        setFocus: useFormOriginal.setFocus,
      };
      useFormOriginal.setValue = createPreservedMock(
        useForm.setValue,
        spySetValue,
      );
      useFormOriginal.reset = createPreservedMock(useForm.reset, spyReset);
      useFormOriginal.setFocus = createPreservedMock(
        useForm.setFocus,
        spySetFocus,
      );

      return useFormOriginal;
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're testing components that utilize the `useFormContext` hook from the react-hook-form library, you have the ability to simulate the context value by employing the `jest.mock` function . Now i will assume you have a module that
you use `useFormContext` something like :

```
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

const AddressDetails = () => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();

 
};

export default AddressDetails;
```

Now In your test file, you can mock the `react-hook-form` module and provide a mocked implementation for `useFormContext` here is an example :

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import AddressDetails from './AddressDetails';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

jest.mock('react-hook-form');

// Mock the useFormContext function
const mockUseFormContext = useFormContext as jest.Mock;

// default implementation for register
mockUseFormContext.mockReturnValue({
  register: jest.fn(),
});

describe('AddressDetails', () => {
  it('should render properly', () => {
    render(<AddressDetails isEdit={false} />);
    expect(screen.getByTestId('address-details')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

in the above example we are mocking the entire `react-hook-form` module using `jest.mock` . Then we provide a mocked implementation for `useFormContext` by using `jest.fn()` for the register function . when doing it this way  the `useFormContext` is called inside your `AddressDetails` component during testing, eventually it will use the mocked implementation

Hope this works out for you